# imacros extraction to csv file not sorting by row because of EANF errors

Tags: javascript, imacros

When I extract TXT by html tags into a csv file, everything works perfectly except:

Everytime a  #EANF# (Extraction Anchor Not Found) appears (meaning the html element does not exist) imacros skips to the next valid html tag. In the end the csv file looks like this:

```
bla sdjafl jsdfkl
```

```
bla #EANF# #EANF#
```

instead of what I need:

```
bla #EANF# jsdfkl
```

```
bla sdjafl #EANF#
```

my js looks like this:

```
    var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";

macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";

macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:hit_address EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:hit_phone_no EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:hit_fax_no EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:website EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" +"\n";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:email EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=0" + "\n";
macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*" + "\n";

for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay(macro);
iimGetExtract(i);
}
```

Any help on saving the extractions row by row would be very much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make this JS? Maybe you should split your macro into multiple macros. That would enable you to do some test before save. You can use CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER as a test.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it and report on it tomorrow